# How to handle multiple datetime-formats within a dataset?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

within a dataset, there are several different datetime-strings.

For example:

2020-11-16T06:00:00Z

2020-11-16T06:00:00+01:00

2020-11-16T06:00:00+01:00Z

2020-11-16T06:00:00+02:00

2020-11-16T06:00:00.000Z

I thought about replacing everything after the seconds, but it gives me errors, when for example +01:00 isn't given in the first place.. or else.

Do you have any clou, how to handle this?

It would be absolutely enough, if I could get:

%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M

(The basics, how to strp and strf are known...)

I've wrangled my head all night about this problem.
Hope, that one of you have got a solution...

thank you in advance!

Comment: These are all basically IS8601 formatted datetime strings, see [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-do-i-parse-an-iso-8601-formatted-date)

Comment: Note that `2020-11-16T06:00:00+01:00Z` is not actually correct, the `Z` indicates Zulu time, but the `+01:00` contradicts this

Comment: Thank you, I just wanted to state different time formats and did not take care of correct formats. These were meant just to be examples. I've found a simple solution for my problem and stated it at the end of this topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dataset is generated by a scraper, which scrapes news pages.

Therefore the datetime is scraped as string in the first place, so that the conversion has to take place for several different occurrences, before a strptime can be executed.

I found a solution for my problem, which was influenced by all of the approaches of you guys.
'''
date = '2020-11-16T06:00:00+01:00'
splitat = 19
date = date[:splitat]
date
'''

This resulted in the standardized format, which I needed:

```
'2020-11-16T06:00:00'
```

Comment: This is what I suggested in my answer (`d[0:19]` is the same as `date[:splitat]`). StackOverflow is not a typical internet forum, so no need to post replies just to say "thanks". Instead you should pick an answer that best helped you in finding a solution and click the check mark next to it to accept it as the answer. I am glad you found a solution that worked for you!

Comment: Thank you (nevertheless, in my opinion polite manners are getting rare everywhere these days ;-) ). Do you mind to give my a hint, where to look your example up? From my limited point of knowledge, I was not able to realize, that (d[0:19]) is analog in his behavior to date[:splitat]. I'd like to read this up and learn.

Comment: You could look for tutorials that cover topics on lists and strings. This is really a question of string manipulation, but in Python strings share a lot of similarities with lists in terms of the way you can use `[x:y]` square brackets to index into them. In this case, `d[0:19]` works out to be the same as `date[:splitat]` because you can leave out the starting index and it will default to zero.

Comment: A lot of internet tutorials are not very well written though, so if you really want a cleanly-written and well-edited place to learn from, I'd go for one of the introductory books from o'reilly. They have several Python books, but 'Think Python' might be a good place to start.

Answer (score 3):

Python has a standard library that deals with this problem:

```
import dateutil.parser

examples = [
    '2020-11-16T06:00:00Z',
    '2020-11-16T06:00:00+01:00',
    '2020-11-16T06:00:00+01:00Z',
    '2020-11-16T06:00:00+02:00',
    '2020-11-16T06:00:00.000Z'
]

for e in examples:
    try:
        print(dateutil.parser.parse(e))
    except ValueError:
        print(f'Invalid datetime: {e}')
```

Result:

```
2020-11-16 06:00:00+00:00
2020-11-16 06:00:00+01:00
Invalid datetime: 2020-11-16T06:00:00+01:00Z
2020-11-16 06:00:00+02:00
2020-11-16 06:00:00+00:00
```

@Z4-tier also has a solution for your examples(be careful with just leaving off the end of the string though), but `dateutil` will also deal with more exotic stuff:

```
print(dateutil.parser.parse('15:45 16 Nov 2020'))
```

Result:

```
2020-11-16 15:45:00
```

Also note this:

```
        print(dateutil.parser.parse(e).tzinfo)
```

If you add that, you'll see that `dateutil` includes the information about the time zone in the result, which would be lost if you only parse the first part of the strings.

Comment: ahh, `dateutil`. good idea. But why does it choke on `2020-11-16T06:00:00+01:00Z`? I think that's a valid ISO date.

Comment: It's not - the Z indicates Zulu time (UTC+0), but the +01:00 indicates it's actually an hour away from Zulu time.

Answer (score 1):

how about this:

```
import datetime

dates = ['2020-11-16T06:00:00Z',
         '2020-11-16T06:00:00+01:00',
         '2020-11-16T06:00:00+01:00Z',
         '2020-11-16T06:00:00+02:00',
         '2020-11-16T06:00:00.000Z']

for d in dates:
    datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(d[0:19])
```

Since each date has the same format up to the offset and timezone, just strip that part off of the string and cast it to a `datetime.datetime`.

Comment: Note that your code simply ignores the timezone indication, since you only parse `[0:19]` for each date string.

Comment: @Grismar yep, I know. Since the post asked for `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M`, I am assuming this is acceptable (and if it is, it's probably the fastest way to get there).

Comment: Given the example data includes time stamps both in zones `+01:00` and `+02:00`, I'm betting OP will run into a need to know the difference. After all, those are an hour apart.